# trying to test a code that scrape from yahoo finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a python beginner but I like to learn the language by testing it and trying it.

so there is a yahoo web scraper code to scrape the last price of a specific stock, but it doesn't work with me I don't know the problem.

..

The code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb?p=FB')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")
    price = soup.find('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}).find('span').text
    return price

while True:
    print('the current price: '+str(parsePrice()))
```

error :

```
price = soup.find('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}).find('span').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

maybe it's an easy thing but remember I'm a beginner.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lxml` as a parser instead of `xml`.

There's no need to convert `parsePrice` to a string when printing, since it's output is already a string.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parsePrice():
    r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb?p=FB')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    price = soup.find('div', {'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}).find('span').text
    return price

print('the current price: ' + parsePrice())
```

Outputs:

```
the current price: 216.08
```